# Is it true that every associative algebra is a subalgebra of a unitary associative algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I know from this proposition we can get "there is always a faithful representation of any associative algebra", but I have difficulty to prove it.

Comment: Yes, you can always freely adjoin a unit: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/unitalization

Comment: Thanks you! Though my knowledge about category is rather elementary, the reference provides me with enough hints to complete my proof.